# Cutting one's nails at night

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, evening-night, practical-kabbalah, nail-cutting, personal-hygiene

I recently asked a friend if I could borrow his nail cutter, but he told me that he would prefer I do it in the morning because it isn't good to cut one's nails at night. When I asked him why, he told me it's some *kabbalah* stuff but he wasn't sure. Another friend also told me this, but he didn't know the details. I had never heard of something like this and it seemed kind if weird. Is this a thing? What is the reason for this?

Comment: http://www.yahadoot.net/Answer.asp?id=322

Comment: @hazoriz Thanks, but you can't take for granted that everyone on this site is hebrew-fluent. I personally can't understand at that level.

Comment: @Gabe12 I do not take it for granted (I myself was not fluent at all until recently) but if someone askes me I will be happy to do a Jew a favor

Comment: @Gabe12 He brings a source that explains the reason why it should not be done (even after midday) and then brings a few sources (including the source that why it should not be done) that halachakli it is ok

Comment: @hazoriz And what is that reason?

Comment: @Gabe12 My unprofessional translation "since night is the time of judgements (opposite of kindness), and also nails are a place of impurity, and we should not cut them and provoke the forces of impurity in their time, which is night, similar to there are those that say that according to the secret (kabolo) it is forbidden to get a haircut at night."

Comment: Others don't worry about these sorts of thins and regard them as mere superstitions. Note that apparently not clipping nails at night is a non-Jewish superstition. http://en.rocketnews24.com/2015/03/26/clipping-your-nails-at-night-may-cause-death-according-to-a-japanese-superstition/

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Dershowitz at [Dinonline](http://dinonline.org/2015/12/20/cutting-nails-at-night/) quotes the following regarding a source for not cutting nails at night:

> See Shu”t Yechave Daat from Rav Ovadia Yosef 4:20 who quotes from Rav
>   Chaim Palagi that according to the kabala one should not cut hair or
>   nails by night. Rav Ovadia disputes this, and claims that there is no
>   problem according to halacha or kabbala to do so at night.

The great answer hazoriz [linked](http://www.yahadoot.net/Answer.asp?id=322) seems to be saying the issue of cutting nails at night is due to "nighttime being a time of judgement. Therefore, cutting the nails, which are an area of tumah, would be considered tantamount to awakening the powers of tumah."